# Can I use a pivot table to count cell values in columns and group the result by column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have several ranches I want to manage with common tasks across each ranch. I've made a table to track my progress:

| Tasks | Dry Valley | Rocking Horse | Whisperwind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Herd Cattle | Done | ToDo | In Progress |
| Put up fence | ToDo | ToDo | Done |
| Feed Horses | Done | In Progress | In Progress |

Is it possible to create a pivot table that will create a summary of statuses for each ranch? i.e.

| Status | Dry Valley | Rocking Horse | Whisperwind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ToDo | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| In Progress | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Done | 2 | 0 | 1 |

I can create this summary for each ranch individually by placing the Ranch in the pivot table Row and Values areas, but adding more ranches seems to lock the values to the first ranch in the order like this

| Status | Dry Valley | Rocking Horse | Whisperwind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ToDo | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| In Progress | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Done | 2 | 2 | 2 |

Comment: I found a way to do this if I make a "ranch" column and create a row for each ranch-task combination. Unfortunately, my actual data has many more rows (~80) and columns (~16) and I don't really want to maintain ~1300 rows. I'm afraid I may be out of luck.

Comment: Would COUNTIF or COUNTIFS work for you? It would be easy to create the formula once and just drag it over and down. Otherwise, if you restructure data to 3 columns (ranch, task, status) then you can use pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pivot table will not work well based on your current data structure. You could use COUNTIF formulas, or change the data structure, or consider power query. Here are a couple of those solutions:

**Option 1**: Keep structure as-is, use COUNTIF formula:

```
Cell B10 formula: =COUNTIF(B$3:B$5,$A10)
```

Drag is over and down, done.

**Option 2**: Restructure your data to have 3 columns (Ranch, Task and Status) and then use a Pivot table.

[image]

Comment: I ended up going with a `COUNTIFS` solution as a stop gap. If Access were more accessible (pun intended) I'd like to port this to a database since there are many more rows, many more columns, and large potential for both to grow. The other half of my problem I failed to mention is have a multiple people in here checking off tasks. So the ergonomics of the table are important to me. Frankly, non of the tables formatted for pivot tables look very intuitive, at least to me.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since it does in fact answer the question, albeit not in the way I hoped.